# screen command not showing status bar

Tags: gnu-screen

I have a `~/.screenrc` file that contains the following lines:

```
# 2.2) hardstatus = navigation bar @ bottom
hardstatus alwayslastline "%H %-Lw%{= BW}%50>%n%f* %t%{-}%+Lw%<"
```

I have to admit that I don't know about the magical syntax there, but it has worked on countless Ubuntu machines to show something like this at the bottom of my terminals:
[image: screenshot]

That line only shows up, of course, when I'm actually running the `screen` command in the terminal.

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04.5 server amd64 on VirtualBox 4.2 and I'm not seeing that status bar at the bottom of my screen. The .screenrc file is exactly the same as it is on my other machines.

What could be going on?

Comment: I'm having a very similar problem. The difference is that I use `hardstatus alwaysfirstline` to show the status in the top line, and I use `caption always ...` to show a detailed info on the current window in the bottom line. The `caption` thing works in Ubuntu 14.04, while the `hardstatus` thing doesn't, while the same `.screenrc` file works totally fine in Linux Mint 18.2. It looks though that the version of screen on Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't support 'alwaysfirstline' option for `hardstatus`...

Comment: In my case, the status bar was visible after I killed all current screen sessions and stated a new session.

Answer (score 2):

As you've stated, your status line works fine in my own .screenrc - good lookin', too.

From within a new screen session, enter `^a` followed by `:` to initiate command mode (a prompt will appear at the bottom of the screen), then enter `source $HOME/.screenrc` (I've seen `~` fail to work in some instances).

If that doesn't work, again from command mode, enter `echo $HOME` to see where GNU screen thinks your home directory lies.

Comment: You should not `source` screenrc. It has nothing to do with `screen` (https://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do)

Comment: @user13107, you mean the shell command `source` which is not what is meant in the answer.  The answer means the screen command `source` (https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Source.html) that can be entered after getting into command mode (https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Colon.html). It will then read a file containing screen commands.

Comment: This worked for me (with the caveat that to enter command mode, you must do `^a` and then `:`  -- edit has been proposed.